# Daily summary of all outlook meetings for the day in email or notification form

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

Is there a way to get a daily summary of all outlook meetings for the day?

Email form would be fine, as would a smartphone notification. I would set it up to notify me at 9AM or perhaps at breakfast time.

I often work on client sites where I don't have access to my laptop with outlook, however I still want to know of any off-site meetings that I have agreed to attend. At the moment the best I have is a notification coming up on my smartphone before the meeting, but I would prefer to know at the start of the day and get a summary.